# sap.m.DateTimePicker: minutesStep required

Tags: sapui5

It's about the **sap.m.DateTimePicker**. I need the possibility to display only the following minutes values: 0, 15, 30, 45.

The sap.m.TimePicker has the property "minutesStep" for that.

Can such a functionality be made available for the sap.m.DateTimePicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some private API is used if you want to achieve this. NOT RECOMMEND.

Though please check this running [example](http://jsbin.com/suqadusore/edit?html,output)

```
        var oPicker = new sap.m.DateTimePicker({

        });

        oPicker._createPopupContent = function(oEvent) {
            sap.m.DateTimePicker.prototype._createPopupContent.apply(this, arguments);
            oPicker._oSliders.setMinutesStep(15);
        };
```